# email share intent android - html styles are not working

Tags: android, email

I tried following code

```
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                shareEmailSubject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                Html.fromHtml("<b>text to be shared</b><br><a href=\"www.example.com\">link</a>");
```

but when I send the email, no styles are appearing while 
1. sending the email
2. After email is received on desktop email client(eg. gmail)

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and it is working fine at my end

```
   String body = "<b>text to be shared</b><br><a href=\"www.example.com\">link</a>";

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hi");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml(body));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I was facing was due to default android mail client, when I switched to share via gmail, it worked perfectly fine.